# StandAloneContext Koin instance is null

Tags: android, koin

As I added Koin to a project, I keep running into the following error.  `StandAloneContext Koin instance is null`

`implementation 'org.koin:koin-android:1.0.2'`

**Modules.kt**

```
val UIModule: Module = module {
    factory<MainContract.Presenter> { MainPresenter() }
}

val appModules = listOf(UIModule)
```

**App.kt**

```
class App : Application() {

    private val TAG : String = Application::class.java.name

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        startKoin(this, appModules)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After a whole afternoon wasted of me trying to figure out this issue, and short of just dropping Koin altogether, I checked my App class one more time and finally paid attention to the yellow warning highlight from Android Studio over the `App` class....

Turns out all I needed to solve this was to add the application class to the manifest... ‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application android:name=".app.App" ... />
```

If this helps even 1 person not waste a whole 4 hours, then it was worth me posting this question/answer here.

Cheers!